# What is pm.Normal.dist.logp?

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc3

I'm reading [Probabilistic Programming and Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers). In Ch5, it is written that `logp = pm.Normal.dist(mu=price_estimate, sd=(3e3)).logp(true_price)`.

What is this? I know `pm.Normal()` but don't know `.dist()` and `.logp()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pm.Normal` creates a new random variable and adds that to the model. `pm.Normal.dist` represents the distribution itself, it does not interact with the model at all. `pm.Normal.dist(...).logp(value)` is the log of the probability density function (or probability mass function if the distribution is discrete) at the point `value`.